# Including C++ Boost on Windows with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost

I would like to include and to use the boost library (https://www.boost.org/) in Visual Studio Code. Here my test.cpp:

[image]

I get an error after running my code in VS Code with the arrow in the top right corner:

[image]

I also add my .json-file:

[image]

I don't know if it's sufficent to include the boost-folder in .json file like that. The folders with .hpp files are in a subdirectory of "boost_1_80_0".

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance

Jacob

Comment: Please do not post images or links. All code, configurations and errors should be included in the question as formatted text.

Comment: Note that the file in the `#include` statement is appended to the include path(s) to try and find the file.  So does `c:\program files\boost_1_80_0\boost\numeric\odeint.hpp` exist ?  If not, either adjust the file in the `#include` statement, the include path or both.

Comment: Use `/` instead of ``\`` in `#include`. Probably makes no difference on Windows, but would help on other platforms.

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` only configures intellisense in your IDE. To make the compiler find the library, you need to add some compiler flags (`-Ipath/to/include/dir`, most likely).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Where should I add the compiler flags?

Comment: read the VSC C++ tutorial doc pages on using a launch config and build task, don't use the Run button

Comment: I don't use the code runner extension (which you seem to be using?), so no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and fixed it, as HolyBlackCat suggested, by adding a `-I path/to/include/dir` compiler flag to the `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder in the folder of the project.
The tricky part was, that the `"-I"` and the `"C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_84_0/"` were separate items under `flags` section, as follows:

```
"args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_84_0/", 
            ]
```

For reference, the whole `task.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/nologo",
                "/Fe${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "C:/Program Files/Boost/boost_1_84_0/", 
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```